# Multiple Rewrite Rules in a .htaccess File

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having problems with url rewriting.

Here's how my .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog\/$ /blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\/$ /blog.php?action=listposts&categoryid=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog\/featured\/([0-9]+)\/$ /blog.php?action=listposts&categoryid=featured&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\/([0-9]+)\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\/$ /blog.php?action=viewpost&postid=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know why, but it doesn't work. For example, when I go to a url like `blog/my-category/1-5/` and print out `$_GET`, it has no keys, as if I was on the url `blog/`.
Sorry for this question as it most likely is a duplicate, but I really don't know what to do and I guess I wouldn't understand what the problem is based on a solution to somebody else's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rules are processed in the order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) in which they're encountered (top down). Also you're escaping a few things that do not need to be escaped. `-` Hyphen characters inside of brackets `[]` at the end do not need to be escaped. If they're between things they're treated as ranges (eg. `[0-9]`). The slashes `/` do not need to be escaped, but sometimes the trailing slash (depending on your settings) may not be required, so I've added a `?` character to make them not always required.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?action=listposts&categoryid=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/featured/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?action=listposts&categoryid=featured&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/?$ /blog.php?action=viewpost&postid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /blog.php [L]
```

If you've used the `preg_` functions in PHP that might be where your slash escaping habit is coming from as a lot of online examples and books use the `/` characters as delimiters.

Comment: You are likely right regarding my 'escaping habits'. Thanks for fixing my rewrite commands, they are working now, but they do so only if the file I'm redirecting to is not called 'blog.php'. Any way around this? I guess this must be related to my Apache configuration...

Comment: @MatejGolian There is likely a RewriteCond somewhere that says `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`. It will be one of the rules following it that tells them to redirect to the default file.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such command in the .htaccess file. The code I posted is all it contains. But I have noticed that if I for example type 'asd' or 'asd/' or 'asd/anything' into the address bar and there is a file called 'asd.php' in the directory where my .htaccess file is, I get the content of 'asd.php'. Is it related to Options +FollowSymlinks or something else? I guess that this is why I can't redirect requests to 'blog.php'.